# How to assign and store value of element from one arraylist to another in java

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I have output from data in ArrayList, I have below two ArrayList, where the price of first ArrayList in second ArrayList.
I want to use the price for particular items to calculate the bill with some formula. I want to store the value eg. Apple=200.

> Formula: Bill = Apple + (10 * Cake)
>
> I have used HashMap.I have never used HashMap before. Or is there any
> other way to store values?

```
    ArrayList<String> name = {Apple, Cake, ice-cream, Milk, Burger, Eggs}
        ArrayList<String> values = {200, 350, 75, 80, 200, 100}
        HashMap<List<String>, ArrayList<String>> nameWithvalues = new HashMap<>();
                nameWithvalues.put(name, values);
```

**Output**

```
nameWithvalues :{[Apple, Cake, ice-cream, Milk, Burger, Eggs]=[200, 350, 75, 80, 200, 100]}
```

Comment: Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>(); since you want to put each item individually, right?

Comment: @SSC Yes I want individual values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start a loop and put the values from both the arrayList . Value from first arrayList will be the key and other will be the value

```
HashMap<String , Integer> nameWithvalues = new HashMap<>();

for(int i=0 ; i < name.length() ; i++ )
 {
  nameWithvalues.put(name.get(i), values.get(i));
 }
```

Comment: Make sure to check for IndexOutOfBounds exception.

Comment: @Umesh Sanwal, Thanks I got values in {{Apple=200, Cake=350}, But how can   I use in my Formula? like; int bill = Apple + (10 * Cake); ??

Comment: int bill = nameWithvalues.get("Apple") + (10 * nameWithvalues.get("Cake));